# Porque mi onsubmit aunque devuelva false sigue el flujo del Formulario. (LARAVEL)

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, laravel

tengo un pequeño problema que no entiendo y a ver si alguien me lo puede aclarar.
Os dejo el código del HTML y el código JS , el cuál recoge perfectamente los datos del AJAX para hacer la comprobación que preciso.
Añado que tengo una tabla llamada Users en la base de datos de la cuál obtiene los datos de la petición AJAX (exactamente los roles que sean admin) y en caso de que el email pertenezca a un rol admin deberían parar el flujo del Formulario lo cuál no sucede y de ahí radica mi pequeño problema. Espero su ayuda o consejos para una respuesta que permita entender que es lo que sucede. Gracias por adelantado.

```js
function validarFormulario2(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });
      $.ajax
      ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/pedir",
        success: function (data) {
          guardado = data.response;
          comprobarEmailCliente(guardado);   
        },
        error: function(){
            var notify = document.getElementById('notify');
            notify.innerHTML = "";
            notify.innerHTML = "<div> Ha ocurrido un error inesperado.</div>"
                               +"<div>  Intentelo de nuevo más tarde.</div>";
        }
    })
}

function comprobarEmailCliente(datos){
    var emailInput = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var notify = document.getElementById('notify');notify.innerHTML = "";
    var rol;

    for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
        if(datos[i].email == emailInput){
            rol = datos[i].roles;       
        }   
    }
    
    if(rol == "admin"){
        notify.innerHTML = "<div>Email no encontrado.</div>";
        emailInput.value="";
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}"  onsubmit="return validarFormulario2()">
                        <input type="hidden" name="roles" value="cliente">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Dirección de email') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Contraseña') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Recordar contraseña') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Iniciar sesión') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Olvidaste tu contraseña') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto, pasa el evento onsubmit como parametro a tu función

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}"  onsubmit="validarFormulario2(event)">
```

después en tu formulario debes prevenir el comportamiento por defecto del evento onsubmit

```
function validarFormulario2(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Lo he probado y me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Estoy optando por validar el dato desde la parte back-end y ayudarme del front-end